# Formatting string to keep trailing zeros *to runtime-set precision*

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python (3), I would like to write a number to a string and keep trailing zeros to a specified precision.  The trick is (and why this question is different from others I've seen on this site), the precision is to be specified at run-time based on other factors, and the precision will not necessarily be the same across all the numbers I am writing to a string.

Something like

```
'{0:.5f}'.format(number)
```

But with the `5` being a variable.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You can provide the precision as a variable too
`'{0:.{prec}}f'.format(number, prec=5)`

Comment: To those marking as duplicate, can you please direct me to the question this is a duplicate of?